# How to export Google API keys automatically on every login for Chromium in Sierra?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have tried writing launchd.conf, but it is not working. 
I have edited Info.plist, but no luck!
Writing launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf in .profile not working either!

[image]

How can we do this without exposing keys in .profile?

Answer (score 1):

[Try this method](https://github.com/ezeeyahoo/ChromiumSyncEnabler)

It is easy and safe by not exposing API keys to environment.